# Create new spreadsheet with selected data from another sheet depending on the activeUser

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

first of all, this is the case:

I do have a masterdata sheet with lots of employee details (database). Column G contains email-adresses. I try to find a way to separate/select the lines for which the email-address matches the active user email-address. Without any opportunity for the user to change anything.

I tried different approaches with Query and IMPORTRANGE within the spreadsheet (e.g. `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("101kbFw_DQGjmxhrw7BHK5-SM5IShkddre7GdqEhc2-U";"Data!A1:AC100"); "Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col7='Pascal Richter'")`. But in this case the user would be able to change the name.

So I tried to build a webapp with the following functionalities:

1. the script identifies onOpen the activeUser
2. Button "send me data" starts the function `createSSwithselectedData ()`
3. the function `createSSwithselectedData ()` creates a new spreadsheet
4. the function `createSSwithselectedData ()` looks up the lines where the activeUser and the email in column g matches
5. the function `createSSwithselectedData ()` transfers the identified data to the new spreadsheet
6. the activeUser gets an email with a link to the new spreadsheet

This is a dummy of the [masterdata sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/101kbFw_DQGjmxhrw7BHK5-SM5IShkddre7GdqEhc2-U/edit?usp=sharing).

Help is highly appreciated :)

```
 // Log the email address of the active user
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
Logger.log(email);

var DatabaseID = "101kbFw_DQGjmxhrw7BHK5-SM5IShkddre7GdqEhc2-U";
var Data       = SpreadsheetApp.openById("101kbFw_DQGjmxhrw7BHK5-SM5IShkddre7GdqEhc2-U").getDataRange().getValues();
Logger.log(Data);



function doGet() {
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
// create a button and give it a click handler
var button = app.createButton("Send me data!").setId("button");

 button.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("createSSwithselectedData"));
   app.add(button);
   return app;
 }

   function createSSwithselectedData(email) {
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   app.getElementById("button").setText("Data is on the way");
   return app;

  var SheetTemplate = "1Z-ECGaRXaO8mEjTCx74z4sXOc_B7ZU81qfhtVJ3TAic";
  var SheetName = "Jobgroup validation - ";
  var newSheetName = SheetName + email ; 
  var folderId = "0B45D8-yA6A-HTWF1MjNhZW1VaXM"
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var copyId =  DriveApp.getFileById(SheetTemplate).makeCopy(newSheetName,    destination).getId();
 var copySheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(copyId);

  // this is a new array to collect data
  var target = new Array();
  for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){                                   //   iterate    in the array, row by row
   if (data[n][7]==email){ ;                                   // if   condition is true copy the whole row to target
                        target.push(data[n]);                // copy   the whole row
                       }                                     //if
  }                                                             //for

  copySheet.getRange(1,10,target.length,target[0].length).setValues();

  // Save and close the temporary document
  copySheet.saveAndClose();

  var url = copySheet.getUrl(); //DriveApp.getFileById(newFileId);
  var link = "<a href=\"" + url + "\">" + newSheetName + "</a>";
  var subject =  "Jobgroup validation - " +  email;
  var body    = "<p>You requested your team details. Please check the content.</p></br> " +  link;
  MailApp.sendEmail({to: email, subject: subject, htmlBody: body, name: alias, noReply: true}); 

  }
```

Comment: What does not work about the web app approach? Is it a web app or just a macro?

Comment: The log shows, that the email address of the active user be properly read out and gets the values from the datasheet. But it's not creating the new Sheet and sets the selected values neither.

What do you mean with macro? Macros reminds me to excel. Sorry, I forgot to paste the script:

Comment: Well, can you paste it now?